# Is there a way to align columns in HTML table?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a basic form, including a table, at the beginning of an Angular project, but I can't get the columns to align.

I've tried all manner of permutations with the styling for HTML `<table>` elements `<table>`, `<tr>,``,``,`width`, 'float' etc., and have tried using vertical bars``.

My code borrow heavily from a W3Schools page, https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro, so it's strange that it doesn't align (not only don't the columns align, but the alternate row coloring also doesn't work).

```
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 5%;
  }

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 50%;
  }

  tr {
    width: 100%;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #522a2a;
  }
</style>

<form style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%">
  <h3>Form</h3>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Input</th>
    </tr>
    <div *ngFor="let key of memberKeys">
      <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="member[key]" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/></td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Not sure why the columns don't align, and the rows don't alternate background color. Many thanks for some advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `div` where the table expects a valid child element such as `tr`:

```
<table>
    <tr>[...]</tr>
    <div *ngFor="let key of memberKeys">
```

Try moving the div to another location so that the table rows are all siblings.

Comment: In fact, he should remove the `div` tag and apply the `*ngFor` directive on the `tr` element.